# using pull-up resistors with A-star 32u4 on putput pins?

Tags: arduino-mini

Okay probably not the first time this has been asked, but really, I search all over the internet and was not able to find this.
I want to drive LEDs on the output on some of my pins. Is it required to put a pull-up resistor or current limiter resistor on these? or can I just plug the LED into the output, and the other end of the LED to +vcc? Are there example schematics someplace that will show this?
thoughts? suggestions?
thanks.

Comment: Have you asked Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always should use a resistor.

Simply the following schematic should be used.

The resistor value can be calculated as follows:

(V + Vfwd = I * R) => R = (V + Vfwd) / I

V is 5.0 V
Vfwd is the forward voltage of the LED (this differs per type/color/brand)
I is normally max. around 20 mA (but can be briefly more if the LED does not continuously lights)

Normally R is between 100 and 500 R, but can differ if you want to add multiple LEDs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiEF1Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>